# Predicting Y Values Properly in a Regression Task using Scaled Values (Random Forest & MLP)

Tags: regression, random-forest, forecasting, feature-scaling, mlp

I have a supervised learning regression task: I am trying to forecast demand for a product based on sales in past years.

**Data description:**

**Samples (rows) -** Demand for a certain product (at a certain month, in a certain year). Number of rows: 2,400

**X Variables (columns) -** Explanatory variables. Most of them are categorical (which I turned into dummy variables), 2 of them are continuous ("Price Per Unit", "GDP"). Number of X variables: ~20

**Y Variable (target):** Demand in units.

I decided to use Random Forest Regression and MLP Regression for the task, using Python & scikit-learn.
For both models, I used StandardScalar to scale the continuous values, and then used RandomSearch for hyper-parameter tuning to find the optimal model.

**My question:**

After finding the optimal parameters, do I need to fit the model again (with the same optimal parameters) but on the original, un-scaled values? (Is the scaling meant to be only for FINDING the optimal parameters?)

Also, when **predicting** values for new data: do I need to scale the values again, or do I just use the original, un-scaled data? (If I scale them, the model will return scaled Y predictions, which I cannot interpret as a solid demand in meters...)

Comment: if scalijng is used (there are valid reasons to re-scale data), then it is used everywhere, in training in testing in prediction, in hyper - search everywhere

Comment: But then I get a scaled predication, instead of the demand forecast. Then what?

Comment: You only scale the X, not the Y.

Comment: @10xAI that was my problem... Thanks!!